# Raspberry:lauch a webbrowser(or any DISPLAY) on startup

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I've been searching on net but no proper solution for the moment.

[Raspberry Pi: Launch Python Script on Startup](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/)  
This guide tells the way to lauch a python on startup.

The key of this guide is the following crontab command:

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/bbt/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

I tried it.It works well only when there is NO operation to open a web or any other display within the python script.
If I want to lanuch a webbrowser using python,this crontab does not work well.

I checked the log and it says:

> xhost: unable to open display ":0.0"
>
> no protocol specified
>
> test.py :cannot connect to X server :0.0

So this is a DISPLAY problem.
This is my shell(named laucher.sh) ,mainly used to lauch python:

```
#!/bin/bash
xhost +local:root
export DISPLAY=:0.0
python /home/pi/test.py
```

Anyone knows about this DISPLAY problem? Please help....
Thanks a lot!

Sincerely,Helen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think crontab is not a very useful way to open a DISPLAY on startup because when you open a DISPLAY it requires X server.AND you don't know whether X sever is enabled before the command "@reboot" running or after it running during the process of booting.

I solved this problem by doing the following configuration.

1.Enter these command in terminal:

```
sudo cd ~./config/lxsession/LXDE-pi

sudo nano autostart
```

2.Add one command in autostart:

```
@python /home/pi/test.py
```

For this example I'm opening a python program that will open a display on startup.
you may replace the above code with any application that opens a display.There might be some slight difference with the grammar but this whole thing is like a conception proving this is also a possible way.